# Best way to iterate over an array and call functions in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, loops

I have this code in coffescript

```
copy pages.template  for pages in configFiles.pages
```

That generates this code in java script

```
var pages, _i, _len, _ref;

_ref = configFiles.pages(function() {});
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  pages = _ref[_i];
  copy(pages.template);
}
```

But what I want is to call 2 more functions inside the for like this:

```
var pages, _i, _len, _ref;

_ref = configFiles.pages(function() {});
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  pages = _ref[_i];
  copy(pages.template);
  copy2(pages.template);
  copy3(pages.template);
}
```

I don't know if this is a good practice or not. I am new in the programming world. 
If it is how can I do this in coffeescript ? If not what is the best solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of nesting it in a comprehension, you can use block syntax for loops:

```
for pages in configFiles.pages
    copy(pages.template)
    copy1(pages.template)
    copy2(pages.template)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unrecommended, but it is technically possible to cram them into one line:

```
(copy pages.template; copy1 pages.template; copy2 pages.template) for pages in configFiles.pages
```

Answer (score -1):

In coffeescript you can nest list comprehensions/for loops. So you could do things like that.

```
(copy pages.template for pages in configFiles.pages for num in [3..1])
```